# If $\frac{\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}$ show that $a^a \cdot b^b\cdot c^c=1$ .

Tags: logarithms

> If $\frac{\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}$ show that $a^a \cdot b^b\cdot c^c=1$ .

***My Working:***

## $\frac{\log a}{b-c}= \frac{\log b}{c-a}$

## $ (c-a)\log a=(b-c) \log b$

## $ \log a^{c-a}=\log b^{b-c}$

## $ \frac {a^c}{a^a}=\frac{b^b}{b^c}$

## $ \frac {a^c \cdot{b^c}}{a^a} =b^b\qquad \text{(i)}$

Similarly, taking the next two terms we obtain,

## $b^b=\frac{b^a \cdot c^a}{c^c}\qquad \text{(ii)}$

I tried to solve the two equations obtained to get to the desired statement but I couldn't. Is the way adopted correct or is there another way to reach the desired answer. Please help me proceed with this question

Comment: Don't we even get $a=b=c=1$? From your calculation above follows $a^a b^b c^c = (abc)^a = (abc)^b = (abc)^c$, from which we get $a=b=c$ and then $a^{3a} =1$ gives us $a=0$ or $a=1$. Maybe it doesn't hold for complex values though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is given that $$\frac{\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}\tag1$$

Now $$\frac{\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log a+\log b}{b-c+c-a} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text {(by Addendo)}$$
$$=\frac{\log ab}{b-a} \tag2$$

So from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get that  $$\frac{\log c}{a-b}=\frac{\log ab}{b-a}$$
$$\implies ab =\frac {1}{c}\tag3$$

From equation $(i)$ established by you in the question and $(3) $,  we get $$\frac {a^c \cdot{b^c}}{a^a} =b^b$$
$$\implies  a^c \cdot b^c=a^a \cdot b^b$$
$$\implies  \frac {1}{c^c}=a^a \cdot b^b$$
$$\implies  a^a \cdot b^b \cdot c^c= 1$$

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7):

Call $k$ the common value of
$$\frac{\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}$$
and then
$$\log(a^ab^bc^c)=a\log a+b\log b+c\log c=\left(a(b-c)+b(c-a)+c(a-b)\right)\cdot k=0$$
which implies that $a^ab^bc^c=1$.

Comment: Thanks, could you also add how I could proceed with my method as I wasn't able to get to the answer using my method

Answer (score 4):

Let $\frac{\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}=t\ $ implies $a=e^{(b-c)t}$, $b=e^{(c-a)t}$ & $c=e^{(a-b)t}$

so now, using values of a, b, c: $$a^ab^bc^c=e^{a(b-c)t}e^{b(c-a)t}e^{c(a-b)t}=e^{(ab-ac+bc-ab+ac-bc)t}=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 3):

We use following property
if $F=\frac{A_1}{B_1}=\frac{A_2}{B_2}$
then 
$$F=\frac{A_1+A_2}{B_1+B_2}.$$

So, your equality implies

$$\frac{\ln(a^a)}{ab-ac}=\frac{\ln(b^b)}{bc-ba}=\frac{\ln(c^c)}{ca-cb}$$

$$=\frac{\ln(a^a)+\ln(b^b)}{cb-ca}$$

thus

$$a^a.b^b.c^c=1.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second step

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the answer of Robert Z, but poorly explained (division by $0$!).

Comment: @ArnaudD. Please look again. i edited.